# JavaScript How to use "this" with onchange event and select element

Tags: javascript, html, this, children, closest

I have got several select tags and divs in my html:

```
<div>
    <select name="one" id="oneId" class="selectOne" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="" disabled selected>choose*</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="2">No</option>
    </select>
    <div class="show" style="display:none;">
        <input type="number" value="" id="other"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to do semething like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var a = this.value; // to select this "select tag" of this function
    var b = this.closest("show"); // to select closest "show div" to select tag
    var c = b.children; //input // to select input in "show div"

    if (a == 1) {
        b.style.display = "block";
        c.removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        b.style.display = "none";
        c.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = this.value; // to select this "select tag" of this function
  var b = this.closest("show"); // to select closest "show div" to select tag
  var c = b.children; //input // to select input in "show div"

  if (a == 1) {
    b.style.display = "block";
    c.removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    b.style.display = "none";
    c.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select name="one" id="oneId" class="selectOne" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="" disabled selected>choose*</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
  </select>
  <div class="show" style="display:none;">
    <input type="number" value="" id="other"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main problem is with selecting proper elements (read the comment tags)

Comment: Maybe you should forget the inline listeners, and take a look at [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=addEventListener).

Comment: Change `this.closest("show");` to `this.closest(".show");` as `.closest()` takes a CSS selector and `show` is a class, not an element.

Comment: [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) looks for ancestors, but that `div.show` is a *sibling* of your `select` element. Just use `this.nextElementSibling`.

Comment: You should take a look at [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback) and how to use the [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object that is passed. That solves your problem of your `this` inside your listener-function.

Answer (score 2):

## Referencing the event target

`this` will differ depending on how the listener-function is added to an element.

You can add a listener using …

1. … [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). `this` will be the element it is added to.
2. … [`HTMLElement.onevent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) – where `event` of `.onevent` is an actual event name. `this` will be the element it is added to.
3. … inline `onevent` listeners (e.g. using the HTML-attribute `onchange="myFunction()"`). `this` will be the global object, see [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis).

It is generally recommended to use `EventTarget.addEventListener()` for multiple reasons. Here are two of many reasons why you should use it:

1. It allows for multiple listeners to be added instead of just one.
2. Using it will keep your HTML clear of JavaScript, separating functionality from structure. Use JavaScript to add functionality, not HTML.

Here is an example demonstrating the ways of adding listeners:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', log); // Case 1
document.querySelector('button:nth-child(2)').onclick = log; // Case 2

function log() {
  console.log((this === globalThis ? "'this' is 'globalThis'" : this));
}
```

```html
<button>Using addEventListener()</button>
<button>Using Element.onclick</button>
<button onclick="log()">Using onevent-listener</button> <!-- Case 3 -->
```

To make it more consistent, one can use `Event.target`. The event-object is usually passed as the first argument. Using inline `onevent` listener would require you to pass the event-object `event` yourself.

Using `Event.target` will always return the event-target, regardless of what way you choose to add the listener.

The modified code would look like this:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', log); // Case 1
document.querySelector('button:nth-child(2)').onclick = log; // Case 2

function log(evt) {
  console.log((evt.target === globalThis ? 'test' : evt.target));
}
```

```html
<button>Using addEventListener()</button>
<button>Using Element.onclick</button>
<button onclick="log(event)">Using onevent-listener</button> <!-- Case 3 -->
```

## Finding other elements relative to an element

This is accomplished by using the `.querySelector()` function of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) or [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to query for children, and the [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) function to query for ancestors. Both functions require a String containing [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors) to be passed.

In case you need to find a neighboring sibling, you can use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) or [`Node.previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) to find neighboring [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) siblings. This also includes `TextNode`s and similar non-element Nodes.
To only find neighboring element siblings, use [`Element.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) or [`Element.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling).

If your `<div class="show">` will always be the following element after your `<select>`, you can simply use `.nextElementSibling` like this:

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', selectChanged);

function selectChanged(evt) {
  var divShow = evt.target.nextElementSibling;
  
  divShow.style.display = evt.target.value;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="block">Show &lt;div&gt;</option>
  <option value="none">Hide &lt;div&gt;</option>
</select>
<div class="show" style="display:none">
  This &lt;div&gt; is shown.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the select element inside the `onchange` function.

You are calling `myFunction()` from that function so, [as per the standard rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), `this` is going to be `window` inside `myFunction`.

If you want to pass the element along then you'll need to do so explicitly (either as an argument or with `apply` or `call`).

---

Better yet, don't use intrinsic event attributes (which have all sorts of issues), and use `addEventListener` instead.

---

Once you've sorted that problem, you'll find that you are using `closest` completely wrong.

It searches *ancestors* not siblings (so possibly you'd want `this.parentElement.querySelector` instead) and, like `querySelector` expects a selector and not a plain class name.